# Save output in multiple text files

Tags: python, cisco

I have a script that will connect to a list of hostnames, run a command, and print the output to the screen. I know how to send the output to a txt file, but i would like to set it up in a way that the output on each host will create its own txt file. Ideally, i'd like to have the file saved as host1.txt, host2.txt, etc. Open to other ideas if there is an easier/smarter way to accomplish this.

```
import sys, os, string, threading
import getpass
import paramiko


cmd = "sh vl bri"
lanid = raw_input("Enter your uname: ")

#get password info
def enterPassword():
  while True: # repeat forever
    pwd = getpass.getpass('Enter password:')
    password_again = getpass.getpass('Confirm password:')
    if pwd != password_again:
      print 'Password and confirmation do not match.Please try again!!'
    else:
      return pwd
pwd = enterPassword()

outlock = threading.Lock()

def workon(host):

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=lanid, password=pwd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    print stdout.read()
    stdin.flush()

    with outlock:
        print stdout.readlines()

def main():
    hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3', ] # etc
    threads = []
    for h in hosts:
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
with open("output-" + host, 'w') as f:
    f.write(stdout)
```

instead of printing stdout on the **workon** function

Comment: i tried that, but im getting indent errors. Still new to scripting so im sure its something easy

    def workon(host):

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, username=lanid, password=pwd)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        #print stdout.read()
      with open("output-" + host, 'w') as f:
      f.write(stdout)
        stdin.flush()

        with outlock:
            print stdout.readlines()

Comment: apologies for the formatting of the previous comment. Still trying to figure out how to paste code into a comment.